# es6 update constructor boolean not working

Tags: javascript

**General Info**
I'm working on a chatsystem based on a websocket. I'm trying to do this properly by using an OOP approach where ever I can. This is what made me decide to go for es6 as well.

**The Problem**
In my code, I'm initializing a couple of variables in the constructor. One of these variables is a boolean used to tell me if a connection with the socket is already made or not. It's set to false and should be updated to true on the `Socket.onopen()` event.

I want to use this boolean in the `connect()` method so that if the user tries to connect again while already connected, it disconnects the user instead. Effectively turning the connect button into a disconnect button after a connection is made.

The problem is that it doesn't update the boolean as I was expecting it to.

**The Code**(simplified to relevant code)

```
class CB {

    constructor(username) {
        this.connected = false;
    }

    connect(){
        // User already connected. Disconnect
        if (this.connected) {
            this.disconnect();
            return;
        }

        const Socket = new WebSocket('ws://'+this.serverHost+':'+this.serverPort);
        this.setSocketEvents(Socket);
        this.socket = Socket;
    }

    setSocketEvents(Socket){
        const obj = this;
        Socket.onopen = function () {
            // Update connected boolean
            obj.connected = true;
        };
    }
}
```

If I try `console.log(obj.connected);` before setting it to true, it returns false as expected. It's also returning true after it's set. But the `connect()` method still returns false on `this.connected` if called afterwards.

I'm guessing this is a scope problem or I'm completely misunderstanding how this all works. So I hope someone here can help me out.

Comment: FWIW, having a flip-flop behaviour like that might bite you later on. A method called `connect()` should never disconnect, at most it should raise an error if you're trying to connect while already connected. Having a flip-flop *button* is something to be handled separately at the UI level.

Comment: @deceze Ye I agree. I'm gonna change my approach on this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a *scope* problem, it's a *timing* problem: For a period of time, you're in the process of connecting but haven't connected yet. You're not allowing for that possibility.

One option for doing so would be to have a separate `connecting` flag. See the `***` comments:

```
class CB {

    constructor(username) {
        this.connected = false;
        this.connecting = false; // ***
    }

    connect(){
        // *** If busy connecting, do nothing (or cancel the connection
        // attempt or ...)
        if (this.connecting) {
            return;
        }

        // User already connected. Disconnect
        if (this.connected) {
            this.disconnect();
            return;
        }

        const Socket = new WebSocket('ws://'+this.serverHost+':'+this.serverPort);
        this.setSocketEvents(Socket);
        this.socket = Socket;
    }

    setSocketEvents(Socket){
        this.connecting = true;
        Socket.onopen = () => { // *** No need for `const obj = this`, use an arrow function
            // Update connected boolean
            this.connected = true;
            this.connecting = false; // ***
        };
    }
}
```

There are lots of variations on this theme. For instance, instead of two booleans, you could have a single enum-like property with values for `NOT_CONNECTED`, `CONNECTING`, and `CONNECTED`.

---

Side note: Strongly recommend not having a method called `connect` that **disconnects** based on state. Instead, have a separate `disconnect` method (which apparently you do, though it isn't shown) that gets called directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this info and advise. I've learned a lot from it :) I agree my approach to this is flawed and I should use a seperate method instead. So I'll have a look at that.